# Загрузка png без потери качества из drawble

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-drawable

Имеется png в drawble, фон для приложения и весит 70 кбайт. Градиент на нем плавный, png-24 с  еще 8 битами на канал для прозрачности. После загрузки градиент лесенкой, кодирован ARGB_8888. Прочитал вот такое:Ресурсы изображений, помещенные в каталог res/drawable/ во время компиляции проекта, могут быть автоматически оптимизированы со сжатием изображения утилитой aapt. Если требуется загружать растровые изображения BMP, которые утилита aapt обязательно оптимизирует, без сжатия, поместите их в каталог res/raw/, где они не будут оптимизироваться. Однако потребуется загрузка с использованием методов потокового ввода-вывода и последующая конвертация графики в растровый рисунок. 
   Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой,  нет ли других решений или только использование raw папки? Что значит методы потокового ввода-вывода? Это загрузка используя доп. поток?

на скриншоте видно изображение из папки drawble и на эмуляторе. на калькуляторе размер битмап в килобайтах https://gyazo.com/8b6a1849b0e2a71afd111a64179467be
До загрузки png весит 40 кбайт

6.04.2017 : Я реализовал загрузку из asset и из res/raw.

```
 InputStream  ims    = mAssetManager.open("gamefield1.png");
 InputStream inputStream =  this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.gamefield);
            field = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
```

В документации было написано, что объекты в drawble могут быть сжаты и я решил для более высокого качества грузить их из raw или assets , но они оказались точно такого же размера и не качественный градиент лесенкой сохранился. 
 Я бы мог предположить ,что исходный png размером в 40 кбайт отображается в системе плавным в силу особенностей формата png. И чтобы лесенки не было нужен еще более качественный png. Но куда уже более качественней , это всего лишь заливка цветом и нанесенный в фотошопе градиент. И  как я понимаю, любой формат изображения перед тем как отобразиться на экране будет переведен в битмап.

Comment: я вижу, что у вас там градиент. проще через shape создать и все

Comment: ну возможно так. в принципе я его вообще могу не использовать, мне интересно,почему он становится лесенкой. Если действительно из-за сжатия, то  через shape задать проще ,чем raw использовать. Сколько будет занимать в памяти битмап из raw понятия не имею, наверно значительно больше. Но все равно хочу попробовать, увидеть

Comment: И кстати есть у меня градиенты, которые в фотошопе сделаны(типо подсветка) их я в shape не сделаю.